# Tkinter: Changing a label text

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm writing a python program with a GUI. For the GUI I use tkinter. In my main window is a button and a label. If the button is pressed I want to change the label and start a request (In the code below, the request is represented as the for loop).

Unfortunally, when trying to change the label on the Button press the API/For-Loop has to finish. After they have finished the label changes it's text.

**Example code**

```
def changeText():
   global label                             #This is just an example and is not used in the main programm
   label.configure(text="Text Updated") 
   for i in range(0,10000000):               #This should represent the API-Call 
       print("Doing something different here")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = tk.Tk()
  label = tk.Label(root, text="Text")

  button = tk.Button(root,
                        text="Click to change text below",
                        command=changeText)
  button.pack()
  label.pack()
  root.mainloop()
```

I've tried to fix the error by myself but I couldn't. I think it has something to do with the focus of the root window. After I start the API-Call/For-Loop I think the window loses its focus and gains it after the call/loop is finished.

Does somebody know how to change the text of a label, when doing something different (like Api/For) afterwards and could maybe tell me if my guess is right or wrong?

Comment: Maybe just add `root.update()` before the for loop.?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA wow, that did the trick. I didn't knew this command existed. Do you know why the label didn't update? Is this because you always need the root.update() command or is this something else?

Comment: Not sure, I think those changes would show after the command finished.But your request blocked your code, so add `root.update()` to update the GUI forcely.

Comment: i believe the prob is because you are saying `label.configure(text="Text Updated")` rather it should be `label.config(text="Text Updated")` and you dont have to say `global label` and also place it after the loop so the change happens after the loop is completed only

Comment: @CoolCloud: `config` and `configure` are both valid.

Comment: @BryanOakley `configure` dint work for me at the first so i tired `config` and it worked

Comment: @CoolCloud: they are literally the same exact function.

Comment: @BryanOakley mayb something to do with the code i formated